# Populate Form Array

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Good night people,
I have the following problem to populate a form array, I managed to develop the code up to a step but now I'm stuck in a step.
I managed to populate the array using setControl, but now I need to populate an array inside this array and I'm having a lot of trouble.
I was able to populate the feedstock array, but I am not able to populate the feedstockOptions array
Follow the code below:

```js
Method populate form

if (response.feedstocks?.length >=1 && response.feedstocks != null) {
  this.feedstockForm.setControl('feedstock', this.editFeedstock(response.feedstocks))              
}
  editFeedstock(response) {
    const formArray = new FormArray ([]);
    response.forEach (s => {
    formArray.push ( this.fb.group ({
      category: s.category,
      position: s.position,
      feedstockOptions: s.feedstockOptions (//this.editFormOptions(s.feedstockOptions))
    }));
  });
  return formArray;
  }
  
    editFormOptions(response) {
    const array = new FormArray([]);
    response.forEach(r => {
      array.push(this.fb.group({
        feedstockOptions: r.feedstockOptions
      }))
    })
    console.log(response)
    return array
    
  }
```

```html
Form
  feedstockForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    feedstock: this.fb.array([
      this.feedstockFormsCategory()
    ])
  });
  feedstockFormsCategory(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      category:  "",
      position: "",
      feedstockOptions: this.fb.array([
        this.feedstockFormsComponent()
      ])
   })
  };
  feedstockFormsComponent(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
     name: '',
     code: '',
     price:  this.fb.group({
       amount: ['', Validators.required],
       currency: ['BRL'],
     }),
   })
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Rod, you can use "map" instead of forEach and push. the "map" array function transform an array in another.

e.g.

```
//Is the same
const formArray = new FormArray ([]);
response.forEach (s => {
  formArray.push (
    this.fb.group ({
       category: s.category,
       position: s.position)
    });
return formArray;

//that
return response.map(s=>{
    return this.fb.group ({
       category: s.category,
       position: s.position,)
    });
})
```

See that we transform an array of object in an array of FormGroup with the values of the array

Well, when you makes the function to create the form, you can pass an object as argument "optional". So your functions feedstockFormsCategory and feedstockFormsComponent becomes like.

```
   feedstockFormsCategory(data:any=null): FormGroup {
    data=data || {category:'',position:'',feedstockOptions:null}
    return this.fb.group({
      category:data.category,
      position: data.position,
      feedstockOptions: data.feedstockOptions?this.fb.array(
                               data.feedstockOptions.map(x=>this.feedstockFormsComponent(x))):
                      this.fb.array([]) //a empty array
                                        //you can also return an array with one element
                                        //if you use
                                        //this.fb.array([this.feedstockFormsComponent()])
      ])
   })
  };

  feedstockFormsComponent(data:any=null): FormGroup {
    data=data|| {name:'',code:'',price:{amount:'',currency:'BRL'}}
    return this.fb.group({
     name: data.name,
     code: data.code,
     price:  this.fb.group({
       amount: [data.price.amount, Validators.required],
       currency: [data.price.currency],
     }),
   })
  };
```

See that you can create a FormArray with the values of the response with only

```
 this.formArray=this.fb.array(response.map(x=>this.feedstockFormsCategory(x))
```